# javascript regex to count whitespace characters

Tags: javascript, regex

Can I use a javascript regex to count the number of whitespace characters before the first text character in the string?  I only care if there are 0, 1, and 2+.

My current working solution is to have three regexes and just use match to determine the 0,1, or 2+ category(separate pattern for each), but Im looking for a more elegant solution.

Is it even possible to count patterns with regex?  I could use a non-greedy grouping and count the length I guess....

Comment: Does 2+ mean two or more?  Is it your intent to produce a count for each kind of string?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
"     a".match(/^\s{0,2}/)[0].length
```

This regex matches between 0 and 2 whitespace characters at the beginning of a string.

Comment: Why not `theString.match(/^\s+/)[0].length` -- the OP means, I think 2+ to mean two or more, although it was strangely worded.

Comment: @Ray: It sounds like there are only three categories.

Comment: correct, only three categories: 0, 1, or 2+.  I also need to get everything after the leading whitespaces, like a java trim.

Comment: to java trim `str.replace(/^\s*(.*?)\s*$/,"$1")`

Comment: @SLaks Oh my bad.  I meant `\s*` by the way.  Good answer!!

Answer (score 4):

You can just do :

```
"   aaa".replace(/^(\s*).*$/,"$1").length
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work when there are zero initial spaces - it returns the length of the whole word.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I'd use a regex in real life for this job, but you can match them in a capture and the see their length:

```
function countLeadingSpaces(str) {
    return(str.match(/^(\s*)/)[1].length;
}
```

A non regex way designed for speed (pretty much anything is fast compared to a regex):

```
function countLeadingSpaces2(str) {
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (str[i] != " " && str[i] != "\t") {
            return(i);
        }
    }
    return(str.length);
}
```

Comment: Why not use `\s*` and get rid of the "matches" check altogether?

Comment: `/^(\s*)[^ \t]/` of an empty string returns null which means you can't directly dereference `[1].length` on a match using it without some sort of check.  I'm not suggesting my method is the most compact, but I was trying to be safe for all edge cases.

Comment: aah, I see - but I think it's returning null since it cannot find the `[ \t]` bit. Since the regexes are greedy anyway, you can just use `^(\s*)` on its own.

Comment: Right you are.  I updated the answer.  This ends up with something similar to what other folks have.

Comment: But succinct and reusable, so +1 for that :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could find the index of the first non-space character in the string,
which is the same as the number of leading white space characters.

```
t.search(/\S/);
```

If you insist you can limit the return to 0, 1 or 2 with `Math.min(t.search(/\S/), 2);`

If there are **no** non-space characters the return will be -1....

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
string.split(/[^ \t\r\n]/)[0].length;
```

Example:  http://jsfiddle.net/Nc3SS/1/

Answer (score 0):

Why *not* just use a capture group and check the length:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script language="javascript">
            var myStr = "  hello";
            var myRe = /^(\s*)(.*)$/;
            var match = myRe.exec(myStr);
            alert(match[1].length);  // gives 2
            alert(match[2]);         // gives "hello"
        </script>
    </body>
</html
```

This can be followed by code that acts on your three cases, a length of 0, 1 or otherwise, and acts on the rest of the string.

You should treat regexes as the *tool* they are, not as an entire *toolbox.*