# How to check if string contains multiple spaces and returns in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to check to see if an item in an array/list of strings has 1 or more spaces and/or 1 or more line breaks.

What exactly would I check for in an `if` statement, if I wanted to check to see if the string item has this?

Comment: What code have you tried yet? Share with us.

Comment: The least you can do before asking a question is search: [`[javascript] string contains space`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+string+contains+space)

Comment: I've tried checking if the item was just a "\n", but that only works if it's one space. I've also tried "\n+" which I thought would mean multiple "\n"s, but it doesn't. I've researched a bit already, but couldn't find anyone else with this question.

Comment: This one pretty much answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17616624/218196 .

Comment: Maybe something like this: `if (/\s*/.test("hello\n")) { alert("foo"); }`

Comment: is your question answered?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly:

```
count = string.search(/\s/);
```

Where string is your input, \s is the regex for space characters, and count is the total number found in string.

Further info here:

**[javascript regex to count whitespace characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867519/javascript-regex-to-count-whitespace-characters)**